# XML PATH in view

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008-r2

I am having a view where five fields (not ID field in it) are used with XML PATH function. The view populates value from a table where ID is a clustered primary key. The view is taking huge execution time and creating a mess. Can any one help.

This is the view I am operating on

```
SELECT t1.ID,
hcp = REPLACE((SELECT t2.hcp AS [data()]--,t2.imstime AS [data()],t2.medtime AS [data()],t2.slntime AS [data()]
                        FROM dbo.STG_HCP_ATTESTTATION_ADDRESS_ATLAS t2
                        WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID
                        ORDER BY t2.hcp--,t2.imstime,t2.medtime,t2.slntime
                        FOR XML PATH('')),
                       ' ', ','),
       convert(Datetime,REPLACE((SELECT t2.hcptime AS [data()]--,t2.imstime AS [data()],t2.medtime AS [data()],t2.slntime AS [data()]
                        FROM dbo.STG_HCP_ATTESTTATION_ADDRESS_ATLAS t2
                        WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID and datalength(t2.hcptime)>0
                        ORDER BY t2.hcptime --,t2.imstime,t2.medtime,t2.slntime
                        FOR XML PATH('')),
                       ' ', ','),127) as hcptime,
      ims = REPLACE((SELECT t2.ims AS [data()]--,t2.imstime AS [data()],t2.medtime AS [data()],t2.slntime AS [data()]
                        FROM dbo.STG_HCP_ATTESTTATION_ADDRESS_ATLAS t2
                        WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID
                        ORDER BY t2.ims--,t2.imstime,t2.medtime,t2.slntime
                        FOR XML PATH('')),
                       ' ', ','),
        convert(Datetime,REPLACE((SELECT t2.imstime AS [data()]
                         FROM dbo.STG_HCP_ATTESTTATION_ADDRESS_ATLAS t2
                        WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID and datalength(t2.imstime)>0
                        ORDER BY t2.imstime--,t2.imstime,t2.medtime,t2.slntime
                        FOR XML PATH('')),
                       ' ', ','),127) as imstime,
         med = REPLACE((SELECT t2.med AS [data()]--,t2.imstime AS [data()],t2.medtime AS [data()],t2.slntime AS [data()]
                        FROM dbo.STG_HCP_ATTESTTATION_ADDRESS_ATLAS t2
                        WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID
                        ORDER BY t2.med--,t2.imstime,t2.medtime,t2.slntime
                        FOR XML PATH('')),
                       ' ', ','),

        convert(Datetime,REPLACE((SELECT t2.medtime AS [data()]
                         FROM dbo.STG_HCP_ATTESTTATION_ADDRESS_ATLAS t2
                        WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID and datalength(t2.medtime)>0
                        ORDER BY t2.medtime--,t2.imstime,t2.medtime,t2.slntime
                        FOR XML PATH('')),
                       ' ', ','),127) as medtime,

         sln = REPLACE((SELECT t2.sln AS [data()]--,t2.imstime AS [data()],t2.medtime AS [data()],t2.slntime AS [data()]
                        FROM dbo.STG_HCP_ATTESTTATION_ADDRESS_ATLAS t2
                        WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID
                        ORDER BY t2.sln--,t2.imstime,t2.medtime,t2.slntime
                        FOR XML PATH('')),
                       ' ', ','),

        convert(Datetime,REPLACE((SELECT t2.slntime AS [data()]
                         FROM dbo.STG_HCP_ATTESTTATION_ADDRESS_ATLAS t2
                        WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID and datalength(t2.slntime)>0
                        ORDER BY t2.slntime--,t2.imstime,t2.medtime,t2.slntime
                        FOR XML PATH('')),
                       ' ', ','),127) as slntime

       FROM dbo.STG_HCP_ATTESTTATION_ADDRESS_ATLAS t1
       GROUP BY ID,med,sln,ims,hcp
```

To process 12K records and cut it down to 10K it takes 1 hr time.There are index on ID column in the original table from where 'dbo.STG_HCP_ATTESTTATION_ADDRESS_ATLAS' view is being operated.

Comment: You need to update your question with the view definition, table definition(s), indexes on the table, the query you are using against the view, number of rows in the table(s), how long your query takes measured in seconds or minutes and how long you think it should take.

Comment: If you doing this often, you can write SQL CLR aggregate function for concatenation. As for your question, your approach to concatenation through xml is not completely correct, and why do you converting it to datetime?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add the table definition with some sample data and the expected output using that data so rewrite of the query can be verified to work as expected.